# error with my code? string index out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why I keep getting the error "string index out of range" and another error on line 47 print_data(data. Can someone please explain why? Thank you

```
def open_file():
  user_input = input('Enter a file name: ')
  try:
    file = open(user_input, 'r')
    return file
  except FileNotFoundError:
    return open_file()


def read_data(file):
  counter = [0 for _ in range(9)]
  for line in file.readlines():
    num = line.strip()
    if num.isdigit():
      i = 0
      digit = int(num[i])
      while digit == 0 and i < len(num):
        i += 1
        digit = int(num[i])
      if digit != 0:
        counter[digit - 1] += 1
  return counter


def print_data(data):
  benford = [30.1, 17.6, 12.5, 9.7, 7.9, 6.7, 5.8, 4.1, 4.6]
  header_str = "{:5s} {:7s}{:8s}"
  data_str = "{:d}:{:6.1f}% ({:4.1f}%)"
  total_count = sum(data)
  print(header_str.format("Digit", "Percent", "Benford"))
  for index, count in enumerate(data):
    digit = index + 1
    percent = 100 * count / total_count
    print(data_str.format(digit, percent, benford[index]))


def main():
  file = open_file()
  data = read_data(file)
  print_data(data)
  file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This is the exact error I'm given

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./lab08.py", line 52, in <module>
    main()
  File "./lab08.py", line 47, in main
    data = read_data(file)
  File "./lab08.py", line 26, in read_data
    digit = int(num[i])
```

Comment: You cut off part of the error message.

Comment: Can you give an example line in the file?

Comment: Can't reproduce the error: we need enough of an input file to provoke the problem.

Comment: @Noura Asrar Do not deface or remove the code from your question - it makes all the answers seem out of context.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the error stems from this:

`while digit == 0 and i < len(num):
    i += 1
    digit = int(num[i])`

If you swap the second two lines, you will properly index, i.e.:

`while digit == 0 and i < len(num):
    digit = int(num[i])
    i += 1`

If, for example, your string `num` is of length 10, then the final element is at index 9 (indexing from 0). for the first iteration of that loop, you will have digit be `num[1]`, for the tenth iteration you would have it be `num[10]`.

An alternative method would be to use list comprehension like this:
`for n in num:
    if digit != 0:
        break
    digit = int(n)`